# Script only changes first <p> element

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

Below is the javascript I have for my page:

```
    window.onmouseover = function(){
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")
        var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")
        for(var j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
            body[j].style.fontFamily = "helvetica";
            body[j].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(250, 250, 240)"
            p[j].style.fontFamily = "courier";
            a[j].onclick = function() {
                this.style.backgroundColor = "Black"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have one h1 element, one a element, and 10 p elements. For some reason, this code only changes the font of the first p element, although everything else works fine? Why is this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one `a` element and (of course) only one `body` you cannot iterate over 10 of them. This causes an error on the second iteration of the cycle. Use this code instead.

```
window.onmouseover = function(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var p = document.getElementsByTagName("p")

    body[0].style.fontFamily = "helvetica";
    body[0].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(250, 250, 240)"
    a[0].onclick = function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "Black"
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
        p[j].style.fontFamily = "courier";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be generating an error the second time through the loop, since `body[1]` would be invalid.  Move things around so that only manipulations on `p` are inside the loop.